# Create ImageField dynamically Django

Tags: python, django, imagemagick, django-models

I have a model, I would like create a thumbnail by ImageMagick( yes with line command ), it works , but I cant associate the image created with the field "mini" in my model MedicoImage.

```
class MedicoImage(models.Model): 
    medico          = models.ForeignKey(Medico)
    imagem          = models.ImageField(max_length=300,upload_to='img_medico')
    mini            = models.ImageField(max_length=300,upload_to='img_medico/mini',verbose_name=u'Miniatura',null=True, blank=True)


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MedicoImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.mini:   
        path_destino = os.path.dirname(self.imagem.path) + '/mini/' 
        path_destino += os.path.basename(self.imagem.path).partition('.')[0] + '_mini' + '.png'
        comando = 'convert ' + self.imagem.path + ' -resize 30% ' + path_destino
        if subprocess.call(comando,shell=True) == 0:
            f = File(open(path_destino,'r'))
            self.mini(path_destino, f.read())
            self.mini.save()
            print 'Thumbnail created!'
```

What is wrong here?

```
            f = File(open(path_destino,'r'))
            self.mini(path_destino, f.read())
            self.mini.save()
```

Comment: Are you using `File` from `django.core.files`?

Comment: Yes I'm importing 

from django.core.files import File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
f = File(open(path_destino,'r'))
self.mini.save(path_destino, f, True)
```

I think that should do it.